# Why am I getting positional arguments here?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following a tutorial to learn how to make a sidebar. I'm pretty confident I was following the steps correctly, but I'm getting the error "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected but 1 found."

I can provide more of the code if necessary. Any line with "selectedIndex" is an error.

```
class _JobPostingsState extends State<JobPostings> {

  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Job Postings')),
      drawer: sideNav(selectedIndex),
      body:Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          if (selectedIndex == 0) {
            return Center(child: Text('Selected index is 0'));
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}

class sideNav extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  Sidenav(this.selectedIndex);...
```

Comment: class SideNav extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideNav({Key? key, required this.selectedIndex}) : super(key: key);

  final int selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("data");
  }
}

Comment: try creating SideNav widget like above, with capital S == The error "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected but 1 found." means your class does not require any constructor value but you are passing 1

Answer (score 0):

Please correct below code

```
class Sidenav extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  Sidenav(this.selectedIndex);...
```

Also this too

```
  drawer: Sidenav (selectedIndex),
```